# Clarify what slot getSlot is returning?

Tags: web3.js

I'm using the `connection.getSlot()` method from `solana-web3` and having trouble understanding exactly what slot it's returning. For context, I'm trying to determine how long (in number of slots) it takes for my `sendTransaction()` calls to appear on the blockchain.

The basic code is:

```
const slot = await conn.getSlot()
const mySig = await conn.sendTransaction(mytx, [keypair], options)
console.log("Slot immediately before tx:", slot)
```

This transaction only takes a couple seconds or so to run; but the number returned by slot is always ~ 40-50 slots behind the block that shows on SolScan. What's the delay? Is there a better function to use to get the most immediate slot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because of the different commitment stati you are using

If you pass in "processed" it will be as soon as the validator processed the transactions "confirmed" will be as soon as 66% of stake voted for the transaction and "finalized" will after 31 blocks. So i guess that is the delay you are seeing. Maybe try:

```
  const slot = await connection.getSlot({ commitment: "confirmed" })
```

and also set the options in the transaction to "confirmed"

Slot delay should be usually around 0-3 slots. With congestion that can increase.

Here you can see some live stats: https://www.validators.app/ping-thing